# how to calculate month difference from two different columns in Sql Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to calculate month difference in same table from 2 different columns. In other words, I have 2 different columns that include dates and I would like to see their month difference in Sql Developer. Is there any way to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: which database ? oracle or mssql ?

Comment: Oracle. im trying to do it sql developer now

Comment: you can use months between , I gave an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for mysql : The [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function can give you the number of days between two dates.

for oracle: [months_between](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm)

sample:

```
SELECT months_between(column1,column2)
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

for the month differnce the standard sql is DATEDIFF, in this function you must pass 3 params, if you must calculate the difference from 2 columns, c1 and c2, you must do this query

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(month,c1 , c2)
FROM T
WHERE ...
```

Here the documentation of datediff https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp

if you use oracle you can use also

```
SELECT months_between(c1,c2)
FROM T
WHERE ...
```

This is the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm